# Building C# App with crystal report to 32/64 bit

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am having a little trouble deploying a program with crystal report to a target 64bit machine. (Program works fine only reports is the issue)

1) I deployed my app for any CPU on the target machine...added the CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_13 and CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13 as dependencies and installed. when running on my target machine I got the error. "The type initalizer for 'crystaldecisions.crysta.report document' threw an exception.
I read and it said to deploy the app to 32bit.

I then did that but here is second issue.
2) When i deploy to 64bit machine(as x86)...my bootstrapper installs the 64 bit crystal report. When i uninstall the 64 and install the 32 manually. reports run fine. So i attempted to delete the 64bit from the set up folder and run my setup.but the setup fails when the 64bit is not in the folder.

3) I then attempted to build the whole project with the 64bit.msi NOT in the prereq folder. which then causes my C# build to error out asking me to place all dependencies in the folder.

Is there a way I can stop my program from needing the 64bit MSI to create the build? or explicitly say to install the 32 bit version?

P.S : Should i got to product.xml and edit is as i like?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I went to the product.xml and commented out everything relating to the 64 bit. I have no idea why this is occurring and this seems like a dirty fix but its the only one i could find...so if anyone has a better way. Feel free to let me know